# Which JavaScript framework for this drag-n-drop UI in a ROR3 website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, drag-and-drop, dhtml, javascript-framework

In a Ruby-on-Rails website, I want to create the following dialog, where a user is shown a list of colors and must choose 3 favorites and 3 least liked colors.

It works by dragging an item from the left and dropping it on the right.
What is the easiest and most maintainable library/method to implement this?

[image: drag drop]

*Notes: I am in the process of choosing a JavaScript framework for this website, so any proposition is fine. If that matters, the real thing is actually: among 15 work situations, choosing 5 that the user feels as most stressful, and 5 least stressful.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI.

It has [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/). It is super easy to use, highly configurable and is the new standard javascript library in Rails 3.1.

Comment: I have found this JQuery sample to be very similar to what I described above: http://plugins.scbfolio.com/